# send sms message from Android app to a device

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, android-wifi

I've implemented code to send sms message from an Android emulator to another, which works well. But when I try to send message from the emulator or an Android device(with wifi only, no data plan or number with the phone) to a device(iPhone ), it doesn't work. I'm not quite sure if sms needs a data plan to send message in real world. Thx for the help!

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though sms does not require a data plan, it needs a working `GSM` or `CDMA` Network connection with call working.

Answer (score 0):

SMS is [Short Message Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service). It's been around longer than we've had internet on phones, and definitely requires a valid SIM card and a working network connection (data over network isn't necessary, but you should be able to make calls).